# UTF-8 Encoding issue in IE query parameters

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8

I have this URL with my test-code: [http://www.gruppenunterkuenfte.de/encodingtest.php?q=köln](http://www.gruppenunterkuenfte.de/encodingtest.php?q=k%C3%B6ln)

It passes the query-parameter q to an SQL query.

The strange thing is, if the query is comming from IE, I have to `utf8_encode()` it. If it comes from Chrome, or Firefox, I may not.

`mb_detect_encoding()` Always says the query is UTF-8 (IE and Other). The query itselfe however will only work in one of the browsers.

This is my test code from the URL above:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$config = parse_ini_file("inc/base/config.php", 1);
$link = mysqli_connect($config["database"]["server"], $config["database"]["user"], $config["database"]["passwd"]);
mysqli_select_db($link, $config["database"]["database"]);
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES utf8;");

echo 'mb_detect_encoding: '. mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q']) .'<br>';

echo 'Without utf8_encode():<br>';

$res = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ort FROM BRDOrte
  WHERE ort LIKE \''. addslashes($_GET['q']) .'%\'
  GROUP BY BINARY ort
  ORDER BY BINARY ort
  LIMIT 5
  ');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) print_r($row);


echo '<br>With utf8_encode():<br>';

$res = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ort FROM BRDOrte
  WHERE ort LIKE \''. utf8_encode(addslashes($_GET['q'])) .'%\'
  GROUP BY BINARY ort
  ORDER BY BINARY ort
  LIMIT 5
  ');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) print_r($row);

?>
```

The MySQL table and all its fields are utf8_general_ci.

So how do I tell IE to send the Query parameter as UTF-8?

Or how do I detect it on server side, so I can encode the right way?

Comment: Generally speaking, IE will not attempt to automatically encode a URL on your behalf. (That's an extremely complicated topic, however, and it differs based on 4 or 5 factors). Your best bet is to be explicit and encode the URL in the encoding you want.

Comment: In addition to Chris' answer, I'll add that you should never let your application depend on `mb_detect_encoding`, since it is imprecise. It will make a guess based on heuristics - which may not be correct. Also, `utf8_general_ci` isn't an encoding, but a collation. The two does not need to match (although they usually will). Finally, MySql has a per-connection charset setting, which will make it convert automatically, so make sure that is set correct.

Comment: That's what I already set with mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES utf8;"); right? But the issue itselfe comes from the URL encoding. I don't think it has anything to do with mysql, since it behaves different depending on the browser

Comment: Umm, SQL injection bug anyone? http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: How? addslashes() is not enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic syntax of a URI ([RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) requires that any characters not 7-bit ASCII are to be percent-encoded (URI Encoded). When you operate outside that standard, user agent handling will vary unpredictably. You will either have to a) encode the URL string before sending it with javascript (see [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)), b) encode it during page render with PHP (see [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php)), or c) create a ternary statement in the request handler to deal with either situation:

```
$tag = strlen($_GET['q']) > 1 ? $_GET['q'] : utf8_encode($_GET['q']);
```

Comment: You're right about the 7-bit ASCII URLs. So encoding them will be the only way. But I think I'll use your code from option c) as well as a fallback, since it detects my URLs correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to pass the query parameter to the browser. It will become `k%F6ln` Then you should be able to read it back with [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

For JavaScript try [encodeURIComponent](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) or its alternatives

Comment: Its JavaScript generating the query-Parameter. What would be the equivalent?

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try something on server side

check and edit /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset  ( Your server may have different directory) and 
add  lines beolow. I realized you use  some Dutch characters, so you may add character for that language also.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-9
```