# Sending UTF8 in GET parameter

Tags: php, utf-8

When navigating to a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/user?u=ヴィックサ
```

I notice that Chrome encodes the characters as:

```
http://example.com/user?u=%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B5
```

And everything works serer-side.

However, in IE I get this error from my code:

> The user you are trying to find (?????) does not exist.

Note the five question marks. For some reason the PHP never gets to see the parameter.

What could be causing this, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @hek2mgl ___However, in IE I get this error from my code:___ ?

Comment: Ok, now I see. :) Would like (?) to have IE for testing

Comment: Which IE version produces the errors? cannot really believe it. (as this would mean whole asia cannot use it) Also note that I'm from germany where we have 'ÄäÖöÜü and ß' .. it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it seems what you want to do is not going to work for the current generation of IE

The accepted answer for this question [UTF-8 Encoding issue in IE query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763799/utf-8-encoding-issue-in-ie-query-parameters) says that you need to encode the characters yourself rather than relying on the browser as support varies from browser to browser, and maybe even device to device

```
<a href='/path/to/page/?u=<?=urlencode('ヴィックサ')?>'>View User</a>
```

Also I presume you are setting utf8 headers from the webserver? you didn't say, if not, in php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Fair enough. I can live with that XD Thanks for the answer.